# SIP SIMPLE PIDF: Convention for "Do not disturb" DND presence extension

Tags: sip, instant-messaging, user-presence

In relation to **[RFC4480](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4480): RPID: Rich Presence Extensions to the Presence Information Data Format (PIDF)** there is no activity for DND: `Do not disturb`.

On the other hand there are many SIP telephone systems on the market that does support DND. Is there a convention to support DND in a "standard" way for presence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DND is a slightly different animal than merely a status, which SIMPLE can accomplish. More specifically, it's a state of the UA that affects *behavior*. In the real world, this is usually implemented by handsets by by returning a 480 Temporarily Unavailable, or in the case of a system acting as a B2BUA, this usually works in concert with SIMPLE to convey user status and the local PBX returns a 480 on their behalf in the first leg of the INVITE. For example, this is how the 3Com VCX does things, and Adtran PBX's.

In a nutshell, SIMPLE could only say you are unavailable, not actually effect it.
To the best of my knowledge this is no standard, and if there is, I have not seen it used. Caveat: my experience is limited to the 3Com, Aastra, and Adtran systems.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer. Related information can be faound in RFC-3261 (Core für SIP) at chapter 21.4.18 480 Temporarily Unavailable.

Comment: Additional reading can be found in SIP implementors mailing-list at https://lists.cs.columbia.edu/pipermail/sip-implementors/2008-April/018968.html There is also a draft regarding DND at http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-elwell-bliss-dnd-01.txt

Comment: In RFC4479 the chapter "3.3.2. Reach Information" is also good to know, because it's not really DND but comparable: *It is also possible for a presence document to contain a service that has no reach information at all.  In such a case, the presentity is indicating that the service exists, but is electing not to offer the watcher the opportunity to connect to it.*